Jalapeño pepper plant dropping flower buds
Someone help me..   Jalapeño pepper plant growing under 6500K cool day LED  grow light continuously dropping flower buds even though leaves are green n healthy right now It’s rainy season. The temperature is around 30°C, so I don’t know what to do.??

Any chance the pot is too small or the soil is already spent?

No offense - I think growing under artificial light can be challenging, but I don't think from looking at the droopiness of the leaves that that plant looks healthy - I think it looks stressed.  (I don't know its right, but https://www.smallspacegardeningbasics.com/will-6500k-led-grow-plants/ says peppers will do better at 2700k.   I'd have thought they care more about the red and blue parts of the spectrum) Also, is it getting enough water and fertilizer - especially potassium?

They probably are not getting pollinated.  You could use a small painter
s brush or a sonic toothbrush to vibrate the pollen and force it to the stamen of each flower.

Or shake the plant violently or play with the flowers with your fingers.

I have experimented with shaking and tapping flower branches daily vs using a Sonicare toothbrush and the results were quite striking.  It sounds crazy, but the toothbrush provided nearly 100% pollination.
